# Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 is scheduled to be released on March 7 2017 as per Microsoft.

My questions are :

1. Do I still need Visual Studio Code for my Angular2/Typescript
   Development ?
2. Will Visual Studio 2017 replace Visual Studio Code or
   will they both co-exists with different strengths like they do now ?

Comment: They are still two separate products.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2017 is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)
Visual studio Code is a [editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor)

1. Even thought VS2017 has improved JS Development experience, it is still not on par with VS Code.
2. They are meant to be used each with for it's own specialty. You may use VSCode to write C# and you might use VS2017 to write JS, but the experience is far better when using the appropriate tool for the specific work.